# How to get shadow effect of button in Kitkat API 19?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to implement google Inbox type button in my application and i put this button in my app but this button gives shadow effect only in lollipop version of android.but i want same effects in Kitkat too like a google inbox app button.
so please guide me . 
Thank you

Comment: You mean the floating button at right side bottom, which is used for composing mail?

Comment: Yes..exactly..u r right..if you know then answer my question

Comment: FloatingActionButton is the widget, there are plenty libs out there.

Comment: Or just make a shadow image and display it underneath the button image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the library that you can use.

https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton